# Power series ring over a ring of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb {Q}_p$ be a finite extension, $\mathcal{O} := \mathcal{O}_K$ the ring of integers of $K,$ $\frak p$ the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}$, and $\pi$ a uniformizer, i.e., $\frak{p} = (\pi).$  We denote $\Lambda=\mathcal{O}[[T]]$ and $\mathfrak m=(\pi,T).$

Can someone give me a reference where I can find a proof of this result:

> $\Lambda$ is a UFD, and is complete in its $\mathfrak m$-adic topology.

Question:

> How to prove the isomorphism $\Lambda/\mathfrak {m}\cong \mathcal{O}/\frak p,$ and that $\Lambda/\mathfrak {m}^t$ is finite of order
>   $p^{t(t+1)/2} $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with finite extensions of $p$-adics ... but rather with the basics of algebra. And $O$ could be any ring.

$$\Lambda/(\pi,T) = (O[[T]]/(T))/(\pi) = O/(\pi)=O/\mathfrak{p}$$

Here are the two trivial facts which I use:

1. If $R$ is a ring and $I,J$ are two ideals of $R$, then there is a canonical isomorphism
   $$R/(I,J) \cong (R/I)/ (J)$$
   (The reason is that both sides represent the functor which maps a ring $S$ to the set of ring homomorphisms $R \to S$ which vanish on $I$ and on $J$, i.e. on their sum $(I,J)$. For the usual proof, have a look at any algebra book.)
2. If $R$ is a ring, then $R[[T]]/(T) \cong R$.

Comment: thank you, can you explain more ?

Comment: why $\Lambda/(\pi,T) = (O[[T]]/(T))/(\pi)$

Comment: Can you calculate $R[[T]]/(T)$ for any $R$? If so, apply some of the isomorphism theorems.

Comment: thank you Martin, for the finiteness of $\Lambda/$$\frak{m}^t$ you have an idea ?

Comment: I looked in books but I did not find it $R/(I,J)\cong (R/I)/(J)$ you have a reference ?

Comment: The projection $R \to R/(I,J)$ has $I$ in its kernel, hence lifts to $R/I \to R/(I,J)$. It is surjective and the kernel is $(J)$ (more formally, I mean the image of $J$ under $R \to R/I$). Hence, $(R/I)/(J) \cong R/(I,J)$.